# is expression ignores immutable/const?

Tags: d, dmd

I'm using a function template `void _createAttr(T)(args..., in T[])` and testing the type of `T` with `static if(is(T == char))` in the function. When I call,

```
_createAttr!char(args...,"someString")
_createAttr(args...,"someString")
```

the compiler never complains.

Of course I know that `alias string = immutable(char)[]`. So in the first call the type of T and the supplied argument don't match, but the `in` modifier should take care of that. And in the second case it should infer `T = immutable(char)`. As I understand it, `immutable(char)` and `char` are distinct types, but the compiler passes the is test in the second case.

The compiler (DMD) seems to ignore the immutableness of the chars in the string when doing the is test.

I couldn't find any explanation for this behavior on dlang.org or in The D Programming Language book.

Is this a compiler bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No bug, it is simply the `in` qualifier expanding to `const`, which is equally valid for both `immutable(char)` and `char`, so the compiler only instantiates it once.

If `T == char`, then `in T[]` means `const char[]` which covers both cases so the template never needs to think about immutability. You could also pass a mutable string to that function without any problems.

If you explicitly did `!(immutable(char))` then it would use that, and no longer accept the mutable one.

Comment: So if I put an `in` qualifier in the function argument list it also applies to the template parameter list? That's confusing.

Comment: No, it only applies to the function parameter, but since you deduced T automatically in the second case, the template parameter is figured out by looking at the function parameter. If you were writing that function by hand, you'd typically write `const char[]`, so since you wrote `const T[]`, the compiler just fills in `T` as `char`.

Comment: The compiler does do several special things with arrays and templates (like strip the outer layer of `const`, since it knows that the array is going to be sliced when it's passed in), so when the compiler is inferring the type of T with `T[]`, it's much more likely to surprise you than if you just use `T`. It's ultimately more user-friendly the way that it is (e.g. it was _very_ annoying when that outer layer of `const` wasn't stripped), so we're better off for it, but it can be surprising at times.